# Can you "hop" between "linked classes" in C++ metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Suppose you have something like this:

```
template<class D>
class HasDef {
public:
     typedef D Def;
};

class A : public HasDef<class B> {};
class B : public HasDef<class C> {};
class C {};
```

So it is like a "metaprogramming linked list", with type links, via the included typedef `Def`. Now I want to make a template "Leaf" that, when applied to `A`, follows the links to yield `C`:

```
void f() {
     Leaf<A>::type v; // has type C
}
```

Is it even possible at all to do this? I've tried some methods with `std::compare` and similar, but none are valid code: everything seems to run into issues with either that `C` has no `Def` typedef, or else that the type `Leaf<>` itself is incomplete when the inner recursive "call" is made so it (or its internal type `type`) cannot be referenced.

FWIW, the reason I want this is for making a "hierarchical state machine" where that `Def` represents the default state for each state in the hierarchy, and something a bit more elaborate that this seems to provide a fairly neat and clean "user interface syntax" for it.

Comment: you're looking for `std::is_detected<>`

Comment: @lorro: I am not sure if I even have that. It looks like it's still called "experimental" and suggests it's not even fully mature in C++20 (and GCC support for C++20 I've not tested but heard is still wanting.).

Comment: Can be done without, likely I can show you an example of it.

Comment: in your example, `HasDef<T>::Def` is both private and inaccessible from descendant. Which is more important: that it descends from a common template, or that you have a `type` in the class?

Comment: @lorro: that was a mistake, actually. fixed.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I assumed `public` inheritance when I wrote my answer. You still haven't changed that.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo : Thanks for that catch too. Yes, you're right. You assumed correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect whether there is a specific member variable in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005476/)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau : The problem was not the detection, but the recursion.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer The recursion is the easy part. You need a detection in order to decide whether to continue or end the recursion...

Comment: @Remy Lebeau : Yes, but my compiler was giving, in one version of the code - that was _not_ the one I gave in the post, apparently, but the one integrated and enmeshed with my main program - some errors about that the struct "ending with the closing brace" because I referenced the included type "type" in a self-referencing typedef to define said type. Detection was already a done deal because I had a class hierarchy similar to the "HasDef<>" thing there for the state machine itself but that distinguishes a leaf from an inner state, and only inner states can have defaults, and

Comment: thus ``std::is_base_of`` sufficed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really like `f(...)` in modern code, thus my version uses void_t from C++17:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class D>
struct HasDef {

     typedef D Def;
};

struct A : HasDef<class B> {};
struct B : HasDef<class C> {};
struct C {};


template <typename T, typename=void>
struct DefPresent : std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
struct DefPresent<T, std::void_t<typename T::Def>> : std::true_type{};


template<typename T, bool deeper = DefPresent<T>::value>
struct Leaf
{
    using Type = typename Leaf<typename T::Def>::Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Leaf<T, false >
{
    typedef T Type;
};



static_assert(std::is_same<typename Leaf<C>::Type, C>::value, "C");
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Leaf<B>::Type, C>::value, "B");
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Leaf<A>::Type, C>::value, "A");
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5h5rfe81o

EDIT: just for completenes, 2 C++20 variants utilizing concepts. Tested on GCC 10

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

template<class D>
struct HasDef {
     typedef D Def;
};

struct A : HasDef<class B> {};
struct B : HasDef<class C> {};
struct C {};

template <typename T>
concept DefPresent = requires(T a)
{
    typename T::Def;
};

template<typename T>
struct Leaf
{
    using Type = T;
};


template<typename T>
    requires DefPresent<T>
struct Leaf<T>
{
    using Type = Leaf<typename T::Def>::Type;
};


static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Leaf<C>::Type, C>, "C");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Leaf<B>::Type, C>, "B");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Leaf<A>::Type, C>, "A");


template<typename T>
struct Leaf2
{
    template <typename M>
    static M test(M&&);

    template <DefPresent M>
    static auto test(M&&) -> typename Leaf2<typename M::Def>::Type;

    using Type = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()));
};

static_assert(std::is_same<typename Leaf2<C>::Type, C>::value, "C");
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Leaf2<B>::Type, C>::value, "B");
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Leaf2<A>::Type, C>::value, "A");
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vcqEaPrja

Comment: Nice! ... and if it's to be used with earlier standards, one could just add `template< class... > using Void_t = void;` and use that. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/oYax74q8x)

Comment: Yes, I agree (on both counts).

Comment: Excellent. Also, C++17 is what I use in this program as it's pretty "fresh", i.e. started recently.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this with SFINAE to separate types that have the typedef from ones that don't when trying to follow them to their leaf. I used the trick from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008673/10362622) here.

The first implementation for `Leaf` follows the typedef recursively, the second one just defines the type itself as there is no typedef to follow.

Also note I changed your classes to `struct` for default-public inheritance. Also I changed the order of their definitions for this to compile.

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwA7KSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEElykAA6oCoRODB7evgHBaRmOAuGRMSzxiVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BQbaY9sUMjc0EpdFxCUm2TS1teZ0KE4MRwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BEcjeWADUJv5uBACeKZgA%2BgTETIQKZ9gmGgCC7x/MbAopTG2xywTTo3xMgSsn2OMOOBEwLBSBnhZwu10YrEwxwAKq9jrNiF4HMc0IIngwFLcsFRTpDvrCGXCEUimCjzlcbr8sXI8bNWXhkCSEM1jhBzAA2eGzCAcjFsY5yEAgAAimBppNmACoVisTABWCxcfXKs5Qj6M2HwxHIzCo2VchW8pqOQXIYXEUUSqUECAAOn9Ov1FjMxtN9It%2BOdApJAlmx1iqE8xwAbmIvFizsrRRkAF6YVBUGWYWao3H%2BbAQDQ607%2BE2145cXX%2BM0MiF1luw8Mwq0stlozmYnGkeOJ2jHYUKGtZ0mgilUtWl15K1PeW3lruRwnE0KYJg0iEdi1eDJGOHoqdngfynd7u3oh3YpWqqhLkCysPQzuBdvgz/d5k2neV5YmWbx/puRIEMcN4vuc2LDlQYhKHiB4bgyx4RMAl4ZvWZaHrSP6fG2v4fD2No1v2coga83wYaeMEXiCTy0EqMGLuuzYkWRrI4ZRD40Z8dFYTB9wXvag5sXBr7vpxRFyaRAE8UBVE4gJHwEpBxwfOg6DPrS%2BFCccemZqpslfN%2BH5fPJGnEm4%2BnEWZNlQRYxwgFpOnPqibgoXSFmOQ8mnmm52m6Qu5xWOW9l%2BWa3x8i6txMAoSgtBAszoEqeCUgomK3MmqIiQQqJfOWw7eeWTZmnFAoJUlCQ%2BmlGVZTleXnAVqIRdgpWvBVsVRsgNXJfVBDpSAmW3NlbC5flu5UPcXmvF15WmhwawsRweq8H4HBaKQqCcN5ljWPiGxbBmZj%2BDwpAEJoK1rAA1iAeoaPonCSJtN27ZwvAKCAz3XdtK2kHAsAwIgKCoIidAJOQlBoJD9CJMAXBmMkNC0PCxA/RAsQfbEETNJcnCXXDbCCAA8gwtCEwDpBYCwhjAOINP4MQdSOMmxYfZgqh1F48JE7wETwmtO20HgsSPMQlweFgH0PHgLAC2sVAGMACgAGp4JgADuZOcgLMiCCIYjsFIhvyEoagfboyQGEYKDWNY%2Bjiz9kBrKgKS9D9HDfd0bNZC4DDuJ47R6GECzlJUeiFJkAhTH4yQx70QyR8sXQ9A0czx3otT1AI/QtCnIxVOMAzZzUcxF0sVRrAoJ3bHoDyYDsPCrZwG2kFtO17RwqgABzigAtOKkjHMAyCCsjvpcKKB1WJYw64IQJCnOdyTHB48MJKvF0rLw/1aDqpAPU9L0cG9pCK6fXe8D332/VdN1rMDYMbAQKR8zDEBwykUPEFEmJOD9yHiPMeE8GxmGnrwTA%2BAiDEDwOlVGshjbiDNvwQQigVDqBpjbUg2tHgpCVmfDuN9PocDJnzD%2BUECzHGAcPUe49J6QJnhATev8EY70bPvJ%2BawEC7iwIkCAbdz68Cvs9Uhd9bAPwPrdY%2Bj1nprX8O9GmkiZFHzWmYZR3cvqPwBkfDmmMA6SCAA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    template<typename T> struct contains_def {
        template<typename U> static char (&test(typename U::Def const*))[1];
        template<typename U> static char (&test(...))[2];
        static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1);
    };
    
    template<typename T, bool has = contains_def<T>::value>
    struct Leaf {
        using type = typename Leaf<typename T::Def>::type;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Leaf<T, false> {
        using type = T;
    };
}

template <typename T>
using Leaf = detail::Leaf<T>; // expose Leaf to the global scope

template <typename T>
using Leaf_t = typename Leaf<T>::type; // for convenience


template<typename T>
struct AddDef {
    using Def = T;
};


struct C {};
struct B : AddDef<C> {};
struct A : AddDef<B> {};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<Leaf_t<A>, C>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Leaf_t<B>, C>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Leaf_t<C>, C>);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a type trait:

```cpp
#include <utility> // declval

template<class L>
struct Leaf {
    template<class M>
    static L test(const M&); // match L's without Def

    template<class M>        // match L's with Def
    static auto test(M&&) -> typename Leaf<typename M::Def>::type;

    // find matching test() overload, prefer test(M&&):
    using type = decltype( test(std::declval<L>()) );
};

template<class L> // bonus helper types
using Leaf_t = typename Leaf<L>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WMGfjvME1) and [template resolution @ cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/fa00dfa0)

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks! I spent more time carving away unnecessary constructs than on the actual trait :-)

Comment: That's often the way: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/878242-not-that-the-story-need-be-long-but-it-will